# Laravel 8 Class App\Helpers\LengthAwareCustomPaginator not found

Tags: class, laravel-8, helper

I have a Laravel 8 project where I created app/Helpers/LengthAwareCustomPaginator class. Then I run composer dump-autoload and expected the Laravel will be able to work with LengthAwareCustomPaginator class. But I get an error:

> Class App\Helpers\LengthAwareCustomPaginator not found

Can somebody tell me please what I need to do to be able to use this class? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does that class exist? Does it really use that namespace? `app` and `App` are not the same

Comment: There was a typo in filename and composer did not accept it cause it did not fit PSR4 standard.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There was a typo in file name and composer did not accept it cause it did not fit PSR4 standard.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are based on a typo